# Perl - how to get values of tokens

Tags: regex, perl, token, substitution

I am searching how to get tokens values in properties file with Perl.

Given the source property:

```
my $source="application.1.hostname={{DNS_APP}}:{{PORT_APP}}/WHATEVER";
```

And given the target property:

```
my $target="application.1.hostname=test.test.com:8080/WHATEVER";
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
{{DNS_APP}}=test.test.com
{{PORT_APP}}=8080
```

I have no trouble to get the tokens with :

```
my @matches= ( $source =~ /({{.*?}})/g );
```

But then, how to match with their values ?
Is there an easy way, with perl regexps to get these substitutions ?

Another difficulty (but they are execption, so it is not a big deal if this problem is not addressed) is that, sometimes, $target can be

```
my $target="application.1.hostname=test.test.com/WHATEVER";
```

Or

```
my $target="application.1.hostname=test.test.com:8080/SOMETHINGELSE";
```

Or even

```
my $target="application.1.hostname=test.test.com/SOMETHINGELSE";
```

How to deal with that ?

I thank you in advance for you answers.

Regards.

Comment: Are you building a simple template system?

Comment: This is impossible to do in the general case if you don't add some constraints to the problem. Imagine how you would match `X{{A}}{{B}}Z` with the text `XfooZ` ? One such constraint could be that `}}` *must* be followed by a character which may not appear inside the token value.

Comment: If you're not careful, you're going to reinvent `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, at a basic level, you can turn your thing into a named capture for a regex. There's a caveat though - you might need to restrict character sets.

But something like this might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $source = "application.1.hostname={{DNS_APP}}:{{PORT_APP}}/WHATEVER";
my $target = "application.1.hostname=test.test.com:8080/WHATEVER";

$source =~ s|\Q{{\E(\w+)\Q}}\E|(?<$1>.*)|g;
$source = qr/$source/; 
print "Using Regex:", $source,"\n";
$target =~ m/$source/;

#%+ is the special named-capture hash. You can access $+{DNS_APP} for example
print Dumper \%+;
```

Note though - that `.*` is a greedy match, and that will mean without delimitors/anchors between patterns, this will break. You could perhaps define a more narrow character class - I would think `\w` normally, but you also have `.` so perhaps `[\w.]+` - or maybe even `.*?` for non greedy matching instead. This depends rather on what would 'fit' with the types of patterns you're trying to match. If you need to do so with arbitrary patterns, I think you're going to need to need ... something like `regex` to define the match criteria in the first place.

If your 'targets' are purely that pattern - e.g. trailing static words - you can trim you initial pattern with `s/\w+$//` which will reduce it to:

```
application.1.hostname={{DNS_APP}}:{{PORT_APP}}/
```

Which you then regex transform to:

```
(?^:application.1.hostname=(?<DNS_APP>.*):(?<PORT_APP>.*)/)
```

And then get `%+` of:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'DNS_APP' => 'test.test.com',
          'PORT_APP' => '8080'
        };
```

As you're on `5.8.8` - my first advice is upgrade it, because it's 7 year old software, and is long since end of life.

> This variable was added in Perl v5.10.0.

However you should be able to work around by:

```
my @match_names = $source =~ m|\Q{{\E(\w+)\Q}}\E|g;  #capture 'names' of matches
$source =~ s|\Q{{\E(\w+)\Q}}\E|(.*)|g;
$source = qr/$source/;
print "Using Regex:", $source, "\n";
my %results;
my @matches = $target =~ m/$source/;
@results{@match_names} = @matches;

print Dumper \%results;
```

I'm pretty sure there's a way of capturing what matched from the `s` pattern replacement. If I figure out what it was, I'll update.

(As it stands:

```
my ( @match_names ) =  $source =~ s|\Q{{\E(\w+)\Q}}\E|\(.*\)|g;
```

doesn't seem to work as I want - `@match_names` contains the number of replacements.  )

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. I will try this as soon as I can.I tried to generate a regexp from source but did not succeed.I will try your method.

Comment: I get the followinf error when using the piece of code : `Sequence (?<D...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/application.1.hostname=(?<D <-- HERE NS_APP>.*):(?<PORT_APP>.*)/WHATEVER/ at ./test3.pl line 10.` Do you use ?<XXXX> to define a pattern ?

Comment: OK, if I understand weel ?<> is used to name variables. It seems it does not work for me. I am using perl 5.8.8, maybe it is too old...

Comment: This sample definitely worked on my test sample which was on 5.22. 5.8.8 is 7 years old, and end of life. You could probably approximate this with non-named captures.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am going to try tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Which, the upgrade or the alternative solution?